# how can I block pop ups with selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium and coding in python:

I would like to know how I can interact with pop-ups with my code using selenium. I keep getting a pop-up that asks me if the site I am on is 'allowed to show me notifications'. In order to keep navigating the site, I am required to press 'allow'. I am not able to inspect the pop up so I can't get the ID and use a click method like normal. How can I select 'allow'? Thank you!